# Android - Pulling Data from MySQL server using PHP

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, jdbc

Here my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


        String result = "";
        //the year data to send
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year","1980"));
        InputStream is = null;
        //http post
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("dropbox link to php code");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            System.out.println(is);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
        //convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();

            result=sb.toString();
            System.out.println("1 " + result);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        //parse json data
        try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                        ", name: "+json_data.getString("name")+
                        ", sex: "+json_data.getInt("sex")+
                        ", birthyear: "+json_data.getInt("birthyear")
                        );
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The link in the HTTPPost is a download link to the PHP code on Dropbox. That code looks like this:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("host","username","password");
mysql_select_db("1487057_test");

$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE birthyear>'".$_REQUEST['year']."'");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        $output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
?>
```

The problem is that the PHP code does not seem to be "executed" by the HTTPClient. When I do a print of the input stream, I just get back the first two lines of the PHP code. The JSON log does not seem to print at all. Anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: can u post the out put too?

Comment: output of php ? 2 lines of php code?

Comment: hey cant we chat the issue that will be more better here : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34961/stacks28

Comment: The PHP is not printing anything. I am referring to this statement in my code:  System.out.println("1 " + result);

Comment: If there is nothing being printed by the PHP, check your database and other variables to ensure that the query is successful first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you have the json data from ftp server it will work fine, since u r
>   using dropbox for php file, u need to make sure that it works, would
>   suggest you to test service on browser first if it works fine then u
>   can move ahead with code.possibly setup the ftp instead of Dropbox as
>   file server.

Answer (score 0):

modify your PHP to something like:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE birthyear>'".$_REQUEST['year']."'";

mysql_query("set names utf8");
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $output[]=$e;
}

print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close($dbhost);
```

?>